# Nginx Perofrmance is too slow even I did all performance trick

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx

I have Nginx server  , which has these configs  (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/modules/*.conf;

user nobody;
worker_processes  auto;
#worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  40000;
 use epoll;
 multi_accept on;
epoll_events        512;
}


http {






#client_header_timeout 3000;
client_body_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
#client_max_body_size 32m;
#fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
#fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;


    include   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
   open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

  access_log off;
  tcp_nodelay on;
log_not_found off;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

   # keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_comp_level 1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable msie6;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types
    # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
        text/css
        text/javascript
   application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        application/atom+xml
        font/truetype
        font/opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        image/svg+xml;


#client_body_timeout 10;
send_timeout 2;
 keepalive_timeout 60;

    # number of requests client can make over keep-alive -- for testing environment
    keepalive_requests 100000;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I am using cpanel and this is the config of my site

```
server {
    server_name alparslan.qsinav.com www.alparslan.qsinav.com;
    listen 80;

    set $CPANEL_APACHE_PROXY_IP 213.159.7.72;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/alparslan.qsinav.com/combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/alparslan.qsinav.com/combined;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-EXP;
            location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;

}

 location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|eot)$ {
         expires 1d;
         access_log off;
         add_header Pragma public;
         add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400";
    }

    root /home/qsinav/public_html/alparslan/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location = /FPM_50x.html {
        root   /etc/nginx/ea-nginx/html;
    }

    include conf.d/server-includes/*.conf;
    include conf.d/users/qsinav/*.conf;
    include conf.d/users/qsinav/alparslan.qsinav.com/*.conf;

    location ~ \.php7?$ {

        include conf.d/includes-optional/cpanel-fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/var/run/php-fpm/58ea52f18cb33ca4e5a37e3fd6c39780e15caa8c.sock;
   error_page 502 503 /FPM_50x.html;

}

    include conf.d/includes-optional/cpanel-cgi-location.conf;
    include conf.d/includes-optional/cpanel-server-parsed-location.conf;
}
```

the problem that  I have , is when more than 80 users login to my system the system going to be very slow  , and then I have this error  under nginx log

> 2020/11/07 14:27:11 [error] 1958#1958: *627 upstream timed out (110:
> Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
> client: 78.182.232.43, server: domain.qsinav.com, request: "GET /
> HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "fastcgi://unix:/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/var/run/php-fpm/58ea52f18cb33ca4e5a37e3fd6c39780e15caa8c.sock",
> host: "domain.qsinav.com"

then the 503 Connection time out start to appear to the clients .
My server's hardware is High (62 GB For RAM ,10 core for cpu )
as I know the worst server must handle more than 10000 users at same time without any problem and my system can not even handle 80 users ,
so where the problem could be ?

Comment: are you using shared host?

Comment: yes , and I tested with server  on google cloud , and I have same problem

Comment: why are you focusing on nginx? 80 connections are nothing for a webserver. You should focus on what your code is actually doing to serve all those concurrent requests. Your error seems to indicate a PHP-FPM issue meaning it's most likely an issue in your code.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for reply , my code is just logging the user and I am using normal laravel authentication method ,